# Have any systems on any Mars rovers failed (even partially) as a result of a dust storm? (besides loss of solar power)

Tags: mars, rovers, curiosity, opportunity, spirit

Have any systems on any Mars rovers failed (even partially) as a result of a dust storm?

There is the obvious problem of loss of solar power, but the failures there are the result of loss of power. Here I'd like to ask about a system issue directly caused by the storm and the dust *in it*. These might include contamination, mechanical interference, electrostatic charging, abrasion, fouled electrical connectors or bearings...

**below:** from [PIA22486](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA22486) "A self-portrait of NASA's Curiosity rover taken on Sol 2082 (June 15, 2018). A Martian dust storm has reduced sunlight and visibility at the rover's location in Gale Crater."

[image]

**below x2:** From Panorama of Vera Rubin Ridge [PIA22545](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA22545) "After snagging a new rock sample on August 9, 2018 (Sol 2137), NASA's Curiosity rover surveyed its surroundings on Mars, producing a 360-degree panorama of its current location on Vera Rubin Ridge [...] The panorama includes umber skies, darkened by a fading global dust storm. It also includes a rare view by the Mast Camera of the rover itself, revealing a thin layer of dust on Curiosity's deck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: slightly related: [How will the ExoMARS Rover keep it's solar panels dust-free and collecting maximum power?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18262/12102)

Comment: I bet lots of failures can be partially attributed to dust - for example, I believe the main explanation for Spirit's wheel failure was thermal cycling damaging the motor, but I'm sure dust in the mechanism can't have helped!

Comment: @Jack The question works hard to constrain itself to *dust storm*.

Comment: Understood - my example below doesn’t really answer the question, but I like how it shows that even the simplest things can go wrong on Mars because space is *hard*!

Answer (score 6):

Not specifically during a single storm, but:

One interesting case of a partial failure of a system is that of the [optical calibration targets](https://marsmobile.jpl.nasa.gov/mer/mission/instruments/calibration-targets/) on Opportunity, Spirit and Curiosity. They were frequently photographed by on-board cameras (Pancam for Spirit and Opportunity, Mastcam for Curiosity) and the images used to calibrate the colour and brightness of the data to a 'true-colour' standard.

Accumulation of dust on the surface of the targets made this [calibration more difficult](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg19025453-200-dust-guard-will-keep-red-planets-colours-true/) and, as a result, it's thought that the quality of the images suffered.

Fortunately, [occasional wind](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Approximate-true-color-images-of-the-Spirit-top-row-and-Opportunity-bottom-row-Pancam_fig17_251429228) helped keep the targets relatively clean. Furthermore, since the targets are perfectly positioned for imaging, the observation of dust accumulation rates [helped in developing](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/2014EA000073) atmospheric dust models.

[image]

<sup>[Image credit: NASA/JPL/Cornell](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/press/spirit/20050125a.html)</sup>

Comment: @uhoh the ‘occasion wind’ link has some detail on how they used a dust accumulation model to compensate, but I’m not sure how successfully...

Comment: I'm hoping someone will ask separately ;-)