# Why do InSight's solar panels have tall vertical ridges between segments - will these trap dust?

Tags: mars, insight, dust

The NASA JPL News item [NASA's InSight Takes Its First Selfie](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7302) provides a link to the high resolution image [PIA22876](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA22876).

Below I've cropped out the West solar panel array, which shows surprisingly tall vertical ridges that extend the full length of each of the ten segments where it joins adjacent segments.

Are these related to the way the panel unfolds? Do they have a function now that the arrays are fully deployed? I would think they might tend to trap Martian dust blowing in the wind and interfere with any cleaning by subsequent wind or dust-devils, but maybe the effect is just the opposite?

One thing I worry about is what @Uwe had mentioned in comments earlier; that blocking one <s>junction</s><sup>†</sup> cell in a group of series-connected <s>junctions</s><sup>†</sup> cells  causes a much larger current drop than you might estimate from the fraction of the total area covered. In some wiring configurations small shadows can become big problems and big losses.

<sup>†</sup> As pointed out in comments, these are triple-junction cells, so unlike the old silicon cells that had but one pn junction per cell, these have three, stacked directly on top of each other. https://solaerotech.com/

[image: cropped from PIA22876 InSight's first selfie]

---

---

For comparison, Martian dust on top of Curiosty, from [Have any systems on any Mars rovers failed (even partially) as a result of a dust storm? (besides loss of solar power)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31101/12102) cropped from [PIA22486](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA22486)

[image: cropped from PIA22486 Curiosity after dust storm]

Comment: Collecting dust is indeed troublesome, especially in the middle of the panel of course. I would not have placed solar cells there !

Comment: I wonder if the [deployment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtkFhSsqXZQ) is repeatable on site. Retracting and deploying again may not remove all the dust, but it may collect it in the mid fold?

Comment: Honestly, they look purely structural to me, but I don't have any design insight (no pun intended)

Comment: @qqjkztd The requirements seem to preclude repeated deployments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are the radial spars that give the solar array rigidity once it's fully deployed.

[image: UltraFlex solar array deployment]

<sup>Image Source: [The Space Technology 8 Mission; S.F. Franklin, et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Ultraflex-175-Deployment-Sequence_fig2_224639431)</sup>

The landing site for InSight was selected to be a low dust environment. Clearing events are not expected during the time of the mission.

As far as I can tell, dust collection was not a consideration in the radial spar design. However, the InSight solar arrays and batteries were designed to ensure enough power could be drawn even in poor conditions.

**References:**

- [Solar ArrayDesign for the Mars InSight Lander Mission - Giang Q Lam and Scott A Billets](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2016-4520)
- [UltraFlex™ Solar Array Systems - Northrop Grumman](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/SolarArrays/Documents/UltraFlex_Factsheet.pdf)
- [Next Generation UltraFlex Solar Array for NASA’s New
  Millennium Program Space Technology 8 - Brian Spence, et al.](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/nmp/st8/tech_papers/2005%20IEEE%20Aerospace%20Conference%20_Big%20Sky_%20Paper-%20NGU%20ST8.pdf)
- [The Space Technology 8 Mission - Stephen Franklin, et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1655767)
- [18th Space Photovoltaic Research and Technology Conference - NASA](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20050206360)
- [Selection of the InSight Landing Site - M. Golombek, et al.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-016-0321-9)
- [Dust Devil Track Survey at the InSight Landing Sites: Implications for the Probability of Solar Panel Clearing Events - D. Reiss and R.D. Lorenz](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2015/pdf/2070.pdf)

Comment: Is this the first usage of this style of solar array?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No, not even first on Mars. It was used on Phoenix before.

Comment: How can I invoke my "authoritative-sounding yet unsourced" rant if you include so many sources? This is one source for every 11 words; one for every 8.6 *unique words!*