# Gravel on Curiosity Rover?

Tags: mars, curiosity

I was looking at a visually impressive [Panoramic 360 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyvGH87CGWg) derived from photographs taken by Curiosity Rover.

I noticed something curious, what looks like small pieces of gravel scattered across the back of the rover:

[image: a rover with what looks like gravel scattered over it]

Is that debris flicked or blown onto the rover during the landing?

Comment: more [dirty pictures](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18262/12102) of curiosity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Curiosity got showered with gravel and sand as the skycrane flew away. One of the wind sensors was broken in the process: https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-19338870